# implement this variable in java

Tags: java, algorithm

Suppose code is given like this:

```
pattern_mask[pattern[i]] &= ~(1UL << i);
```

What kind of type is this in Java? How do I implement this in Java?

Comment: You should accept some answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java does not have unsigned `long`, but `1L` is a 64-bit signed `long` literal.

#### References

- [JLS 4.2.1 Integral Types and Values](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2.1)

  - For `long`, from `-9223372036854775808` to `9223372036854775807`, inclusive
- [JLS 3.10.1 Integer Literals](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.1)

  - An integer literal is of type `long` if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter `L` or `l` (ell); otherwise it is of type `int`. The suffix `L` is preferred, because the letter `l` (ell) is often hard to distinguish from the digit `1` (one).

---

#### On masking of count operand

The shift count is masked: only lower 5-bits for `int` shift, and only lower 6-bits for `long` shift.

The following snippet shows how due to this, shifting on `1` is different from shifting on `1L`.

```
System.out.println(1 << 1); // prints "2"
System.out.println(1 << 33); // prints "2"
System.out.println(1L << 33); // prints "8589934592"
System.out.println(1L << 65); // prints "2"
```

#### Related questions

- [What’s the reason high-level languages like C#/Java mask the bit shift count operand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311476/whats-the-reason-high-level-languages-like-c-java-mask-the-bit-shift-count-oper)