# Why is (-1 >>> 32) = -1?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why is 1>>32 == 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170412/why-is-132-1)

-1 as an int converted to binary is represented by 32 1's.
When I right-shift it 31 times, I get 1 (31 0's and one 1).
But when I right-shift it 32 times, I get -1 again.
Shouldn't it be equal to 0?

Comment: It looks like Java. I dont know of many languages that define the `>>>` operator.

Comment: I came across this while I was trying to learn the basics of Java, yes, but I didn't tag it so since I assumed bit shifting was a fairly generic concept.

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3170412/why-is-132-1

Comment: In light of User's comment saying he's asking about shifting in general, and not specifically about Java, I think this is *not* an exact duplicate of the link given by @Bstn. That's also why I've added some language-agnostic information after my original answer (which is otherwise the same as the answers in the other question).

Comment: This question is about a completely different operator.  it is not a duplicate

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Java specification explains the [shift operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) as follows:

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is `int`, only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator `&` ([§15.22.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1)) with the mask value `0x1f`. The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 31, inclusive.

The value of `32 & 0x1f` is zero.

If the left operand is `long`, then you get an extra bit for the right operand, expanding the upper limit to 63 instead of 31.

---

In order to have any specific expected value from shifting -1 to the right, you need to specify the underlying binary representation of integers (e.g., two's complement) as well as the number of bits (e.g., 32). Each programming language can define those differently, but in the interest of keeping things simpler for the implementation, they'll usually specify that shifting by more than the number of available bits is not allowed. That's often because the underlying CPU hardware doesn't support it, either. After all, if you want to shift that many bits, the left operand no longer matters since the result will always be the same.

Comment: BTW it means you can get the top bit of `x` using `x >> 63` or `x >> -1` whether x is int or long. ;)

Comment: Shifting may also depend on 32/64 bit system.

Comment: @TheCottonSilk Not in Java; shifting works the same way, doesn't matter if you're using a 32-bit or 64-bit operating system or JVM.

Comment: @Jesper: You are right. I did not notice the Java tag added during later edits :). My comment was general to compilers and underlying architecture to caution not to assume based on one scenario.