# unsigned right Shift '>>>' Operator in Java

Tags: java, bit-shift

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is (-1 >>> 32) = -1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813909/why-is-1-32-1)

The unsigned right shift operator inserts a 0 in the leftmost. So when I do

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(-1>>>30))
```

### output

```
11
```

Hence, it is inserting 0 in the left most bit.

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(-1>>>32))
```

### output

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
```

Shouldn't it be 0?

Comment: For comparison try `-1 >>> -1` and `-1 << -1`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19

If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f (0b11111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 31, inclusive.

that is `-1 >>> 32`  is equivalent to `-1 >>> 0` and `-1 >>> 33`  is equivalent to `-1 >>> 1`
and, especially confusing, `-1 >>> -1`  is equivalent to `-1 >>> 31`