# Can anyone explain me the logic behind this hash-function?

Tags: java, hash

Can anyone explain me the logic behind this hash-function?.

```
static int hash(int h) {
   h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);
   return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);
}
```

I pass the `key.hashCode()` to this function which gives me the hash value. Based on this value and the Array size, i calculate the index of the array. I am just not understanding the operator used here in this method.

1. What does this `^` operator do here in this context. Does it check for !=
2. What does Unsigned right shift >>> do?. We don't have Unsigned int's in Java right?.
3. How are the values 20, 12, 7 and 4 chosen for this function?. Is it
   pre defined or user defined?.

The `key.hashCode()` passed to this hash function is `79847235`. Can anyone explain on what happens inside to return the final hash value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsigned right shift (`>>>`), unlike signed right shift (`>>`), will convert negative numbers into positive numbers before preforming the right shift operation ensuring that the result returns an unsigned positive integer.
A right shift, for example `h >>> 20`, essentially means return the floored integer for `h/Math.pow(2,20)`.
For example for your input `79847235`, as it is a positive number, both unsigned right shift and signed right shift will return a positive integer.
`79847235>>>20` will thus preform:
`Math.floor(79847235/Math.pow(2,20))` which returns `76`.
Next up `h >>> 12` for `79847235` is:
`Math.floor(79847235/Math.pow(2,12))` which returns `19493` 
(which is bigger because we are dividing by a smaller number).
Now we preform an `exclusive OR` on `76` and `19493`.
For example `1^0` is `1`
`1^1` is `0`
If we wanted the AND included, we'd have to use an inclusive OR which is |
Thus `1|1` is `1`
`1|0` is `0`
etc

`1001100` is the binary representation of `76`
`100110000100101` is the binary representation of `19493`
An `exclusive OR` operation would look like this:

`000000001001100` (`76` in binary)
`100110000100101` (`19493` in binary)
`---------------`
`100110001101001` (our result: `19561`)

We're almost done for our first line:
We got this:
`h ^= (h >>> 20) ^ (h >>> 12);`
down to:
`h ^= 19561`

Which is the same as:
`h = h^19561`

Fill in our value for `h` which is `79847235`:
`79847235^19561` is `79827754`
`h = 79827754`
**It is important to remember that our new value for** `h` **is now** `79827754`


Next line:
`return h ^ (h >>> 7) ^ (h >>> 4);`

`h>>>7` is `Math.floor(79827754/Math.pow(2,7))` which returns `623654`
`h>>>4` is `Math.floor(79827754/Math.pow(2,4))` which returns `4989234`

Now that the parentheses are out of the way we have:
`return h ^ 623654 ^ 4989234;`
It is important to preform this left to right.
Fill in `h` and regroup:
`return (79827754 ^ 623654) ^ 4989234;`



`79827754 ^ 623654` is:
`100110000100001001100101010` (`79827754` in binary)
`000000010011000010000100110` (`623654` in binary)
`---------------------------`
`100110010111001011100001100` (`80451340` in binary)

Finally we have:
`return 80451340 ^ 4989234;`

`80451340 ^ 4989234` is:
`100110010111001011100001100` (`80451340` in binary)
`000010011000010000100110010` (`4989234` in binary)
`---------------------------`
`100100001111011011000111110` (`76002878` in binary)

Thus our final result is:
`return 76002878;`

Feel free to check my answer, I double checked my work already.
Due to the nature of exclusive bitwise ORs it can be very difficult to predict whether the result for the hash function will be greater or smaller than our parameter.
For example:
`11^2` is `9` (smaller than our parameter 11)
`17^2` is `19` (greater than our parameter 17)

Comment: There's already the same question and an answer I linked to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335169/understanding-strange-java-hash-function . Since this is also a duplicate I wonder why you answered....

Comment: Ultimater, Thanks for your answer. I really would like to know, Why it is specially 20,12,7 and 4. How they measure the randomness. Most of the answers here say introduce randomness etc. How it is creating that randomness? Why the right shift positions has to be 20, why it cant be 21 or 19?. Can you please explain that too? Sorry if I am missing some basic stuff.

Comment: You could use other numbers too. If you ran every number 0 to 100 quadrillion through the function, you'd see there would be no repetitions in the output no matter what numbers you use in the function. This is because of the nature of exclusive OR. 2^5=7. 7^5=2. 2^7=5. If you ran `i^2` in a loop `for(var i=0;i<100;i++)` and stored the results in an array. You'd see the array would contain every number 0 through 99 with no repetitions. http://jsfiddle.net/e9v2D/.
Thus no matter what numbers you used it wouldn't contain repetitions due to XOR's flip-flop behavior as seen with the 2,5, and 7.

Comment: Why specifically those numbers, the idea of the function is to flop the bits 12 - 20 as well as the bits 7 to 4 on the function parameter then return the result. The idea of the function is to avoid using `object.hashCode() % 20` (assuming you had 20 buckets) to decide which bucket to store to since there tends to be patterns with hashCode() which would make the bucket distribution less likely to be evenly distributed. That is where XOR's flip-flop behavior comes into play to help add a bit more randomness to the hashCode() before you do `% 20` to decide which bucket to send it to.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the below:

```
Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators

~       Unary bitwise complement
<<      Signed left shift
>>      Signed right shift
>>>     Unsigned right shift
&       Bitwise AND
^       Bitwise exclusive OR
|       Bitwise inclusive OR
```

Related to the `unsigned right shift` see: [unsigned right Shift '>>>' Operator in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501233/unsigned-right-shift-operator-in-java)

Also, for >>> I think that:

The >>> operator shifts the bits of expression1 right by the number of bits specified in expression2. Zeroes are filled in from the left. Digits shifted off the right are discarded. So this shifting doesn't respect the sign.

So what does this function do...

- (h >>> 20) divides h by 2 to the power of 20. (it shifts 20 times rightwards). Also,it means that if your number was negative, it will not continue to be so.
- (h >>> 12) divides h by 2 to the power of 12. (it shifts 12 times rightwards)...again same with negatives.
- The two results are then XORed,and then are XORed again with original H.
- Following,more XORing goes on to calculate the final hash.

**Edit:** Noticed this has been extensively analyzed in the accepted answer to: [Understanding strange Java hash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335169/understanding-strange-java-hash-function)