# Mathematical formula for unsigned right shift in java

Tags: java

Is there any mathematical formula for `X >>> Y`. We have formula for `X >> y` and `X << Y` ?
If sombody says what is the value of `5 >>> 2`, how will you calculate the value without converting them in to binary.

Comment: I thought they had >>> in Java for this

Comment: they do have it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501233/unsigned-right-shift-operator-in-java

Comment: Any explanation of **bit** shifting, that doesn't mention **bits**, is rather useless IMO.

Answer (score 1):

`>>>` is a *logical* or *unsigned* right shift.

Unlike `>>`, which is an *arithmetic* right shift (and respects signs), `>>>` treats the left operand more as an unsigned value -- or a sequence of bits -- than a normal number.  It's the *bits* that matter with a logical shift, not the signed value they represent in Java.  So a purely mathematical formula is somewhat pointless, IMO.

If you insist on it, though, the bits of any int `a` -- even negative numbers -- are the same as the lower 32 bits of `a`+2<sup>32</sup>.  So for `a >>> b`, you could find it as ((a+2<sup>32</sup>) mod 2<sup>32</sup>) / 2<sup>b</sup>.

The big problem you'll run into is that 2<sup>32</sup> (and by extension, the sum of it and any non-negative integer) won't fit in an `int`.  You'll need to upsize your values by using `long` (or `double`) in places.  And if `a` is a `long`, then you'll need to learn a bit about BigInteger.  (I'm not even going to bother covering that.)